# "insert into" accdb from c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert-into

I wrote this two codes in c# to write something in a row of a access accdb but they don't work both:

```cs
String tableName = "ARE";
                String query = String.Format(
                              "select * from [{0}]", tableName);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                using (OleDbConnection conn =
                      new OleDbConnection(connection_string))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Open Database Connection
                        conn.Open();
                        OleDbDataAdapter da =
                               new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdB =
                               new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
                        da.MissingSchemaAction =
                               MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

                        //Fill the DataSet
                        da.Fill(ds, tableName);

                        DataRow row = ds.Tables["ARE"].NewRow();
                        row["ID"] = "1";
                        row["Localizzazione"] = "1";
                        row["UO"] = "UO1";
                        row["Coordinate"] = "333;336";

                        ds.Tables["ARE"].Rows.Add(row);
                        da.Update(ds, "ARE");

                    }
                    catch (OleDbException exp)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Database Error:" + exp.Message.ToString());
                    }
```

and

```
 using (OleDbConnection oc = new OleDbConnection(connection_string))
                {

                    string q = "INSERT INTO ARE "
                                + "(ID, Localizzazione, UO, Coordinate) "
                                + "VALUES (@ID, @Localizzazione, @UO, @Coordinate)";

                    OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(q, oc);

                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1;
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Localizzazione", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1;
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@UO", OleDbType.Char).Value = (UO[selectedUO])[1].ToString();
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Coordinate", OleDbType.Char).Value = (e.X - 12) + ";" + (e.Y - 12);

                    oc.Open();
                    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
```

But always tell me "error sintax on isctruction INSERT INTO."
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException

WHY??? :(

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for helping me, but I cannot understand well what it means... could you make me an example or a solution?

Comment: Does your second example work if you bracket the table name? `INSERT INTO [ARE]`  If it does not work, do you get a different error message?

Comment: I'm not sure about Access databases, but in general you should not use a semicolon as a separator. I would recommend storing coordinates as two separate columns, but try a manual insert like `Insert into ARE(ID,Localizzazione, UO,Coordinate) values(1,1,'1','1');`

Comment: "Insert into ARE(ID,Localizzazione, UO,Coordinate) values(1,1,'UO4','1')" give me error again

Comment: try renaming your table, according to Microsoft 'ARE' is a reserved keyword. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266 Also, posting the entire error message and table definition will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'ARE' is a reserved keyword for the Jet DB engine, according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266). You can use square brackets to get around this for now (like `INSERT INTO [ARE]`, but you should really consider changing the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring String q and then string q? It looks like your sql is not written correctly.. spaces, capitalization, etc.

Comment: I wrote two times string q for mistake, in the test i tried both commenting each other. Any solution?

Comment: Sorry, the enter key keeps getting me. Are you sure that all of your table and columns are spelled correctly? The code looks right.